# convex hull algorithm for 3d surface z = f(x, y)

Tags: algorithm, 3d, complexity-theory, convex-hull

I have a 3D surface given as a set of triples (x_i, y_i, z_i), where x_i and y_i are roughly on a grid, and each (x_i, y_i) has a single associated z_i value. The typical grid is 20x20

I need to find which points belong to the convex hull of the surface, within a given tolerance. I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to perform the computation (my customer has provided an O(n³) version, which takes ~10s on a 400 point dataset...)

Comment: n^3 is diabolical: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's quite a lot out there, didn't you search?

Here are a couple with O(*n* log *h*) runtime, where *n* is number of input points and *h* is number of vertices of the result:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chan%27s_algorithm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkpatrick-Seidel_algorithm

Here is a demonstration of four methods, with links to the algorithms:

http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~lambert/java/3d/hull.html

Comment: i did some quick googling, but it was not clear which algorithms could be applied to > 2d

Answer (score 2):

The O(n^3) version is probably Jarvis algorithm for 3d Hull.
Look at [this](http://people.csail.mit.edu/indyk/6.838-old/handouts/lec10.pdf) algorithm, I think is well described:

Comment: [Link only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) aren't ideal, but this one would be hard to summarize. If the link fails, paste it into wayback; it was archived when I checked today. If that fails, google for `jason yang convex hull`.